# Chainlink local unit test: UnrecognizedContract

Tags: solidity, chainlink, hardhat

```
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3)
      at APIConsumer._rawRequest (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol:173)
      at APIConsumer.sendChainlinkRequestTo (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol:110)
```

My unit tests are throwing an error when `sendChainlinkRequestTo` is called. `0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3` is the address of my locally deployed LinkToken.

My unit test is calling the following function:

```
function call()
public
onlyOwner returns (bytes32 requestId) {
  Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfillBytes.selector);
  req.add("get", "https://myapi.com/endpoint");
  req.add("path", "url");
  bytes32 reqId = sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  return reqId;
}
```

Comment: Could you add more information?
Are you following some tutorial or example?

Comment: Hey @SolangeGueiros, I'm just following examples in the doc https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/. The contract works fine when I deploy it on testnet but not in local hardhat

Comment: When you say "local hardhat", are you running HardHat's blockchain simulator, or are you connected to a testnet?
It won't work if you're running on the simulator, because you need to access contracts that are published on the network.
UnrecognizedContract in this case means that the contract isn't deployed locally.

Comment: I think you are right it can't be unit tested